# How to change the width and height of ngx-mat-datetime-picker in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I want to decrease the height of the ngx-mat-datetime-picker popup box.
I am using this below code in my html component.

```html
<mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
<ngx-mat-datetime-picker class="datetimepicker" [disabled]="disableStartandEndTimeOnRecording"  #picker [showSpinners]="showSpinners" [showSeconds]="showSeconds"
                         [stepHour]="stepHour" [stepMinute]="stepMinute" [stepSecond]="stepSecond"
                         [touchUi]="true" [color]="color" [enableMeridian]="enableMeridian" style="zoom: 0.85;">
</ngx-mat-datetime-picker>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.mat-datepicker-content {
  width: 500px;
}
```

you might also want to adjust the size of childs since they have fixed sizes using css classes.